# backed up an image of my HD using Ddrescue want to mount (not virtually) on new HD

Tags: mount

**Background:** Hard drive on Vista laptop developed fault but still works and boots. All important user data recovered and new HD purchased.

Don't want to go through hassle of re-installing/ re-configuring/ downloading all the software so googled and decided to create an `.img` file usind Ddrescue. So far so good.

Now all I want to do is to transfer it to the new drive and *"mount"* that drive so that Windows can boot directly from it.

Ive looked at countless threads but nothing seems (or seems to me) to do what I need. they all seem to focus on recovering just specific data or are Linux specific. I looked up the NTFS configuration tool and have tried to understand the `sudo` syntax but don't want to get it wrong. I've found a Windows tool that sort of does it but again just to get at the data contained within the image.

I sure it is simple and would really appreciate a simple command string to use in Parted Magic or something similar.

many thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be misusing the word "mount".  It means to open a filesystem and attach it somewhere in the filesystem namespace.  It sounds like you want to `dd` the image to the new disk.  Assuming the new disk is /dev/sdb, then that would just be `dd if=foo.img of=/dev/sdb`.  If the new drive is larger than the old one then you will want to fire up `gparted` and expand the partitions to use the new space.

Comment: Hi, Many thanks for your input. Sorry for my misunderstanding of terms. I've now managed to dd the image to a new disk and tried booting but it was not recognised by the bios.

Comment: I should point out that the replacement disk is a SSD in case that has a relevance. I'm guessing that it is something relating to the partition size or offset but dont really understand how to check this. I know this is a bit off topic for this forum (as its Windows) but would appreciate any advice even if it is just a recommendation to another forum to post to. @psusi

Comment: Somehow part of my message got deleted. After not booting I used diskpart to activate it. This time I just got a cursor and no boot. I tried Windows repair which recognised the OS and attempted a repair but again just the cursor. Next time I ran windows repair said there was no problem. Thats where I get to the partition size/offset query. @psusi Thanks Bryn